# How to solve this equality? [3]

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$4x^2 - 6x^4 + \frac{8x^6 - 2x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2}}{16} = 0$$

The equation has a strange look, and as such is probably as it should not be solved. Maybe the roots of trigonometric functions are expressed in terms of angles species $\frac{\pi}{n}$?

Comment: is there also an equility (1) or (2)?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner nope.

Comment: Are you sure about your equation? To get the exact roots, you may need a lot of work (see [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x^2+-+6x^4+%2B+%288x^6+-+2x^2+-+1%2Fx^2%29%2F%2816%29%3D0)).

Comment: @user37238 Yes, I'm defenetly sure. Wolfram gives just a primitivity way to solve. Need more humanity :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have got $$8x^8+96x^6+62x^4-1=0$$ which can be solved by radicals if we write
$$8t^4-96t^3+62t^2-1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$4x^2-6x^4+\frac{8x^6-2x^2-\frac{1}{x^2}}{16}=0$$
$$4x^2-6x^4+\frac{\frac{8x^8-2x^4-1}{x^2}}{16}=0$$
$$4x^2-6x^4+\frac{8x^8-2x^4-1}{16x^2}=0$$
$$\frac{64x^4-96x^6+8x^8-2x^4-1}{16x^2}=0$$
$$8x^8-96x^6+64x^4-2x^4-1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The substitution $x={\sqrt \frac u {2}}$ followed by multiplication by 2 turns it into $u^4-24u^3+31u^2-2=0$ which can be solved exactly by Cardan's formula, but the result is messy.  There are 6 real and 2 imaginary roots (to the original equation).